# vscode how to disable accepting suggestion on pressing tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

When type something, vscode show some suggestions, I press tab. the suggestion will autocomplete what I typing.

Now I want to disable that. I want when I press tab, it will not autocomplete.

I do not want to disable suggestion or autocomplete, I just want to disable the tab thing

This is what I've got in the setting

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": false,
"editor.tabCompletion": "off",
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false
```

problem remains, the tab thing still working

Comment: Check the keyboard shortcuts page (Ctrl+K Ctrl+S) and figure out what commands are bound to `Tab`. (Maybe there is something like 'accept suggestion'?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @HolyBlackCat suggested, disable the command `acceptSelectedSuggestion` which is triggered with a <kbd>tab</kbd> key.  You will end up with this in your keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "-acceptSelectedSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
  },
```

Comment: It was working fine till now..But now it is not working for me. can you confirm?

Comment: @MehbubRashid yeah, no longer works, look for the answers below, they work

Answer (score 4):

Open keyboard shortcuts -> search acceptSelectedSuggestion -> right click and remove command that has 'tab' as Key binding.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer used to work for a long time but now it's not working anymore. I had to modify that into the following to make it work:-

```
{
        "key"    : "tab",
        "command": "-acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when"   : "suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can press 'right arrow' <kbd>></kbd> which accepts what you have written rather than accepting the suggestion

Comment: `ESC` is more intuitive here

Answer (score 0):

There is the `editor.tabCompletion` setting, but strangely, VS Code doesn't use it in all the places I'd expect in its default keybindings (you can see for yourself if you search for `config.editor.tabCompletion`)- namely, it doesn't use it in the when-clause for its default `acceptSelectedSuggestion` binding.

If you want to disable <kbd>tab</kbd> for `acceptSelectedSuggestion`, you can do that by putting this in your keybindings.json file (run `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)):

```json
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "-acceptSelectedSuggestion",
},
```

You could also add the when clause to exact match the default keybinding that this unbinds, but that's not necessary, and can be flaky (if the default keybinding's when-clause changes in a new update of VS Code, like it did for one of the other answer posts here).

You may also want the following:

```json
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "-insertBestCompletion",
},
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "-insertNextSuggestion",
},
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "-editor.action.inlineSuggest.commit",
},
```

Basically, just open keybindings.json and search for "`"tab"`" and find the command IDs that you're not interested in having bound to <kbd>tab</kbd>.