# Changing key for tab suggestion activation in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

In Visual Studio Code, by default the suggestions widget automatically is triggered as code is typed if a relevant suggestion or snippet exists, and the tab key accepts the selected (the top option is automatically selected in my case when the suggestions widget is triggered.

Is there a way to keep these suggestions, but switch to them being accepted by some other key (say enter) but *not* tab? For me using tab to move the cursor often undesirably activates snippets.

I cannot seem to find a setting for this, but I may be misinterpreting what other settings do.

Comment: if you're going to say enter is fine, then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57938988/11107541 because VS Code already supports accepting suggestions with `enter` by default, so you'd just be asking how to disable accepting suggestions on `tab`. is that correct? or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: Yes, I would like to disable `tab` for suggestion activation while keeping `enter`.

Comment: what do you mean by "activation"? VS Code does not use that term. It uses "trigger" for opening the suggestions widget, and "accept" for confirming selection of a suggestion from the suggestion widget.

Comment: Apologies, I mean "accepting" in this case (I wish for the suggestions widget to appear, but for the selected suggestion to only be accepted upon pressing `enter` and not `tab`. I have edited my question according.